# PerformanceTest on Ubuntu

Tags: bash

I'm trying to use PerformanceTest on Ubuntu (https://www.passmark.com/products/performancetest/index.php).

But when I follow the process and run `./pt_linux_x64`, Ubuntu replies:

```
bash: Permission not granted
```

This happens, whether I'm root or not with sudo​.
How to fix this?

Comment: The website claims there is a readme in the download but there is not. I would not trust this ...  I would consider Phoronix test suite myself.

Comment: Alexis, is that really the error you get? Is it not "permission denied"? Does it actually say "not granted"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

see: [passmark.com/support/pt_linux_faq.php](https://www.passmark.com/support/pt_linux_faq.php)

"Permission denied when trying to run from command line?":
You need to enable execution permission for the file.

> Run "sudo chmod +x ./pt_linux_x64" or "sudo chmod +x ./pt_linux_arm32" or "sudo chmod +x ./pt_linux_arm64"")

Of course, since you downloaded the file, you own it and there is no need to use `sudo`, just make the file executable with:

```
chmod a+x pt_linux_x64
```

And then try running it again:

```
./pt_linux_x64
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. problem resolved.